# python string to list (special list)

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to get this string into list, how can i do that pleas ?

My string :

```
x = "[(['xyz1'], 'COM95'), (['xyz2'], 'COM96'), (['xyz3'], 'COM97'), (['xyz4'], 'COM98'), (['xyz5'], 'COM99'), (['xyz6'], 'COM100')]"
```

I want to convert it to a list, so that:

```
print(list[0])
```

**`Output : (['xyz1'], 'COM95')`**

Comment: I tried list = list(str(x)) , but got each caractere as an element of list. I want to have this as an element " (['xyz1'], 'COM95') "

Answer (score 2):

If you have this string instead of a list, that presumes it is coming from somewhere outside your control (otherwise you'd just make a proper list). If the string is coming from a source outside your program `eval()` is dangerous. It will gladly run any code passed to it. In this case you can use [`ast.liter_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) which is safer (but make sure you understand the warning on the docs):

```
import ast

x = "[(['xyz1'], 'COM95'), (['xyz2'], 'COM96'), (['xyz3'], 'COM97'), (['xyz4'], 'COM98'), (['xyz5'], 'COM99'), (['xyz6'], 'COM100')]"

l = ast.literal_eval(x)
```

Which gives an `l` of:

```
[(['xyz1'], 'COM95'),
 (['xyz2'], 'COM96'),
 (['xyz3'], 'COM97'),
 (['xyz4'], 'COM98'),
 (['xyz5'], 'COM99'),
 (['xyz6'], 'COM100')]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the structure is uniformly a list of tuples with a one-element list of strings and an individual string, you can manually parse it using the single quote as a separator.  This will give you one string value every other component of the split (which you can access using a striding subscript).  You can then build the actual tuple from pairing of two values:

```
tuples = [([a],s) for a,s in zip(*[iter(x.split("'")[1::2])]*2)]
print(tuples[0])
(['xyz1'], 'COM95')
```

*Note that this does not cover the case where an individual string contains a single quote that needed escaping*

Answer (score -1):

to convert as list use `x = eval(x)`

`print(list[0])` will give you an error because `list` is a python builtin function

you should do `print(x[0])` to get what you want

Comment: sorry just corrected my answer, x is string, just added the " "

Comment: edited also my answer

Answer (score -1):

You mean convert list like string into list? Maybe you can use `eval()`.
For example

```
a="[1,2,3,4]"
a=eval(a)
```

Then  `a` become a `list`